# Array state variable doesn't render

Tags: reactjs

I have a table that needs to be rendered dynamically so I put in state, the problem is that I can't return it via state , it can only be queried with `forEach` function directly:

This code works:

```
render() {
     let rows=[], rows2=[];
        var PRODUCTS = [
        {id:0,category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$49.99', stocked: true, name: 'Football'},
        {id:1,category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$9.99', stocked: true, name: 'Baseball'},
        {id:2,category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$29.99', stocked: false, name: 'Basketball'},
        {id:3,category: 'Electronics', price: '$99.99', stocked: true, name: 'iPod Touch'},
        {id:4,category: 'Electronics', price: '$399.99', stocked: false, name: 'iPhone 5'},
        {id:5,category: 'Electronics', price: '$199.99', stocked: true, name: 'Nexus 7'}
          ];
     PRODUCTS.forEach((product)=>{
   if( product.name.indexOf(this.props.searchText)==-1 && this.props.searchText!='')
      {return;}
   if(this.props.inStockOnly){
      if(product.stocked){
           if(product.category=="Sporting Goods"){
            rows.push(<ProductRow product={product} key={product.id} onDestroy={this.Destroy}/>)
            }
           else {
           rows2.push(<ProductRow product={product} key={product.id} onDestroy={this.Destroy}/>)
            }
       }
    }
    else {
         if(product.category=="Sporting Goods"){
          rows.push(<ProductRow product={product} key={product.id} onDestroy={this.Destroy}/>)
          }
         else {
          rows2.push(<ProductRow product={product} key={product.id} onDestroy={this.Destroy}/>)
         }
    }

  })
```

And this doesn't:

```
render() {
     let rows=[], rows2=[];
     this.state.products.forEach((product)=>{
   if( product.name.indexOf(this.props.searchText)==-1 && this.props.searchText!='')
      {return;}
   if(this.props.inStockOnly){
      if(product.stocked){
           if(product.category=="Sporting Goods"){
            rows.push(<ProductRow product={product} key={product.id} onDestroy={this.Destroy}/>)
            }
           else {
           rows2.push(<ProductRow product={product} key={product.id} onDestroy={this.Destroy}/>)
            }
       }
    }
    else {
         if(product.category=="Sporting Goods"){
          rows.push(<ProductRow product={product} key={product.id} onDestroy={this.Destroy}/>)
          }
         else {
          rows2.push(<ProductRow product={product} key={product.id} onDestroy={this.Destroy}/>)
         }
    }
  })
```

It triggers this error :

```
product.name.indexOf is not a function
```

## Update

this how I set my state :

```
var PRODUCTS = [
        {id:0,category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$49.99', stocked: true, name: 'Football'},
        {id:1,category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$9.99', stocked: true, name: 'Baseball'},
        {id:2,category: 'Sporting Goods', price: '$29.99', stocked: false, name: 'Basketball'},
        {id:3,category: 'Electronics', price: '$99.99', stocked: true, name: 'iPod Touch'},
        {id:4,category: 'Electronics', price: '$399.99', stocked: false, name: 'iPhone 5'},
        {id:5,category: 'Electronics', price: '$199.99', stocked: true, name: 'Nexus 7'}
          ];

class ProductTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props)
    this.state={
      products:PRODUCTS
    };
    }......
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: Could you show state of your component? Probably one of products haven't field name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @AdrianoReptti said in comments  ,the problem was with name.

Actually in another component i changed the product's name in order to light out if the components is in stock or not :

```
 product.name=product.stocked?product.name:<span style={{color:"red"}}>{product.name}</span>;
```

i fixed the code and  now it runs :)

But it's still weird i thought that the state of a component is private and can only be changed with `setState` and not with the return of a children component.

Answer (score -1):

For me your code is working fine. I have tried in the console. Try to restart the server.

[image]

Comment: normally , in JS it works for strings too  not ? 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: There is a `String.prototype.indexOf()` function. We may argue that `String.prototype.includes()` is a better choice (or even better a case insensitive regex that also ignores leading/trailing spaces and properly handle composed sequences) but OP code is _perfectly_ fine.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti good but even product.name.includes return the same error

Comment: Yep, it was unrelated to your problem. I think AgMr is on the right track: in one of your item `name` is not a string (note that **it exists** otherwise you'd get another error) **but it's something else** (a number or another object, for example). Just double check your code, there is a chance it's not _exactly_ what you posted here.

Comment: Still dosen't work , i think it's because of 'this' binding !?
may be i need to bind this since it loses reference  normally if is called in a callback not ?

Comment: Hardly (no need to bind `render()`), as I said...code you posted is probably not the exact one you're using (and one item has a `name` property which is not a string).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti it's the same code i just copied it and pasted here , and i have check it too.

Comment: Can you post an example where the issue is reproducible?